# How do I send money from account to account using an ATM, within India?

Tags: india, money-transfer

I would like to know how to transfer money from an account to another account, using an ATM within India, which banks allow to transfer money.

If we cannot transfer money from account to account in India, how can I send money online within India without confirmation of account such as required by Paypal. Is there any other service known to you which allow such kind of service.

I am not able to use paypal because they send two small amount of money for confirmation of bank account,since I don't know how much money has been put by paypal as I don't have passbook and I have to go to bank which is not possible, similar is the case of my friend who wants money to be transferred.

What can be done?

Comment: Don't the banks have online banking portals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ATM to ATM transfer is not possible. Do you mean to say account to account transfer using an ATM machine?

Online transfer between account or between an account and credit card is possible.
Almost every Bank offers Online transfers using Internet Banking.

The person wishing to initiate a Debit must subscribe to Internet Banking. Once you login to Internet Banking, you would need to add beneficiary Account [account where you need to transfer funds]. Adding of Beneficiary at times takes a Day for the Beneficiary to be activated. Once the Beneficiary is activated, you can transfer funds. The funds are credited to Beneficiary account within 2 hrs.

If the both the accounts are in same bank, then some Bank's ATM's [HDFC / Citi etc] allow you to transfer funds between account using the Bank's ATM.

Comment: Yes I am meant to say account to account transfer using ATM.Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

In case the other ATM is visa enabled, many bank allows transfer to visa card through their ATM. More details about your banks are required for a very specific answer.

I suppose both banks are Indian Bank, which bank ?